# How to Set focus back to current tab widget after clicking on QTabWidget's cornerWidget?

Tags: qt, focus, qtableview, qtabwidget

Hi I put a QPushButton as corner widget for a QTabWidget to refresh a QTableView in current tab. But if I clicked this refresh button, my QTableView lose focus and so highlighted rows turns gray. Unless I click my tableview again, it keeps gray. Any suggestions will be appreciated.
My goal is to make this corner widget acts like a menu or toolbar-button, which won't change the foucs when clicked.

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first, and then update your question with a minimal code example.

Answer (score 0):

1) In first case you can try to use QFocusEvent (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qfocusevent.html):

```
void focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *)
{
     setFocus();
}
```

2) Or you can try like this.

Own signal is emitted from slot with your push-button (in your class there your button):

```
signals:
     void SignalEmitingFromSlotOfPushButton();
```

In slot of QPushButton you need to emit this signal.
For example:

```
void YourSlotForQPushButtonExample()
{
  //some code
  //do something
  emit SignalEmitingFromSlotOfPushButton();

  return;
}
```

Now you need to write slot to receive your own signal:

```
void SlotForReceiveOwnSignal()
{
   yourTableView->QWidget::setFocus();

   return;
}
```

Oh, and remember about connect it

in constructor:

```
    connect(this, SIGNAL(SignalEmitingFromSlotOfPushButton()), 
            this, SLOT(SlotForReceiveOwnSignal()));
```

Comment: Hi guys, finally I found the solution: simply set the focus-policy of corner-widget to Qt::NoFocus, then it will never get the focus. You focus remains no change.